# Java Class Set Method Sets String to Null even though Not Null Argument Was Passed

Tags: java

I am working in Java in an attempt to create an application to manage a database.
I am using a Scanner class to read a file line by line, and I delimiter the line, and everything works correctly. However, when I call the get method from my class, it returns an empty value, even though an actual argument was given.

This is my method that populates the table in the database.
I have a few print statements in there to try to figure why is this happening, you can see the output below.

```
public void populateStudents() {

        File file;
        Scanner input;

        try {
            file = new File("Students.txt");
            input = new Scanner(file);

            Students students = new Students();

            while(input.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] splitLine = line.split(";");

                for(int i=0; i<splitLine.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(splitLine[i]);
                    students.set(splitLine[i], i);
                }
                System.out.println(students.getFName());

                String query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO Students (Student_ID, FName, LName) " +
                "values (?, ?, ?)";

                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

                preparedStmt.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(students.getStudentID()));
                preparedStmt.setString(2, students.getFName());
                preparedStmt.setString(3, students.getLName());

                preparedStmt.execute();
            }
            input.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Student class

```
public class Students {

        private String StudentID;
        private String FName;
        private String LName;
    
        public Students(String StudentID, String FName, String LName) {
    
            this.StudentID = StudentID;
            this.FName = FName;
            this.LName = LName;
        }

        public Students() {

            this("", "", "");
        }
    
        // Get and Set methods
        public String getStudentID() {
    
            return this.StudentID;
        }
    
        public void setStudentID(String StudentID) {
    
            this.StudentID = StudentID;
        }
    
        public String getFName() {
    
            return this.FName;
        }
    
        public void setFName(String FName) {
    
            this.FName = FName;
        }
    
        public String getLName() {
    
            return this.LName;
        }
    
        public void setLName(String LName) {
    
            this.LName = LName;
        }

        public void set(String data, int i) {
        
            switch(i) {
                case 0:
                    setStudentID(data);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    setFName(FName);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setLName(LName);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output

```
00102;Max;Pelle
00102
Max
Pelle

00145;Jeff;Richied
00145
Jeff
Richied

00132;Alex;Hart
00132
Alex
Hart

62574;Joe;Karch
62574
Joe
Karch
```

This empty line comes from System.out.println(students.getFName());

I really do not understand why is this happening. I've spent several hours trying to find an error but I am unable to.

Comment: "*`switch(i) { case 0: setStudentID(data); break; case 1: setFName(FName); break; case 2: setLName(LName); break; }`*" - I recommend [debugging (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) this code segment.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setFName(FName)` and `setLName(LName)` inside your switch statement. You probably meant to call `setFName(data)` and `setLName(data)`.

If you are using an IDE (also if you don't) you can set a breakpoint in code, use Debug instead of Run and then step through the code (step by step) as it executes and inspect the values of fields, variables, references and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I am suspecting the problem could from the following code:

```
preparedStmt.execute();
```

Instead of calling .execute() call executeUpdate() which allows to insert rows to the database.

Reference: https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface

> public int executeUpdate()     executes the query. It is used for create,
> drop, insert, update, delete etc.